# How to use Transaction Scope rollback for multiple database connections within the same NUnit database test

Tags: c#, integration-testing, transactionscope, nunit-3.0, teardown

I am creating a test that injects data in two separate databases(in separate sql servers), then do some action and verify data on a third database.

Now I would like to teardown all the test data from the three databases after each test, but I am unable to use Transaction Scope when my tests interact with multiple databases

Can anyone please help in how to use transaction scope / rollback feature for multiple connections?

I tried using Transaction scope using the following code, **this works fine on the tests where only one database connection is created** however this does not work on the test where it creates three connections. I use Nunit 3 and .Net core for one project & .Net Framework 4.7 for another separate project, the below error is when using .Net Core

```
private TransactionScope transaction;

        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeTest()
        {
            transaction = new TransactionScope();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void AfterTest()
        {
            transaction.Dispose();
        }
```

I get an error " System.PlatformNotSupportedException : This platform does not support distributed transactions." In my test I use Entity Framework DBcontext to interact with databases. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If u are using .net core I don't think that there is support for distributed transactions !

Comment: I actually have to write these tests for two separate projects one in .Net Core and another in .Net Framework 4.7, so a solution for .Net framework would be helpful, thanks